# сравнение данных не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

я пытаюсь взять обновление, но мой код не работает. подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

url = 'https://www.avito.ru/izhevsk/vakansii?cd=1&s=104'

html = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

l = []


def process():

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        l.append(link.get('href'))
    return l[92]


while True:
    first = process()
    time.sleep(5)
    second = process()
    if first != second:
        print(second)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: откуда известно, что не работает? [ask]

Comment: Почему 92 индекс? Откуда знаете что не работает? Выводили значения `first` и `second` перед сравнением?

Comment: да. значение выходит. также в браузере есть обновления, но в моей программе их нет. индекс 92 - это первое объявление на странице

Comment: Добавьте в код все импорты библиотек, чтобы можно было воспроизвести запуск вашего кода.

Comment: добавил импорты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно имелось ввиду что-то такое:

> pip install pandas openpyxl requests fake_useragent bs4

```py
import json
import re
from html import unescape
from typing import Any, Dict, List
from unicodedata import normalize

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4.element import Tag
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()

base_url = 'https://www.avito.ru'

url = base_url + '/izhevsk/vakansii?cd=1&s=104'

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': ua.firefox})
soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')

offer_re = re.compile(r'iva-item-description.*$', flags=re.S)
salary_format_re = re.compile(r'(?<=\d)(?=[^\d\s])')
salary_tag_re = re.compile(r'price-text.*$', flags=re.S)
employer_title_re = re.compile(r'^style-title.+$', flags=re.S)
employer_tag_re = re.compile(r'iva-item-asideContent.*$', flags=re.S)
location_tag_re = re.compile(r'geo-georeferences.*$', flags=re.S)


def parse_snippet(snippet: Tag):
    position = ''
    salary = ''
    employer_title = ''
    employer_profile_link = ''
    location = ''
    link = ''
    details = ''
    offer = ''

    if isinstance(position_tag := snippet.find('h3', itemprop='name'), Tag):
        position = normalize('NFKC', position_tag.get_text(strip=True))
        link = base_url + link_tag.get('href', '') if isinstance(
            link_tag := position_tag.find_parent('a'), Tag
        ) else ''

    if isinstance(details_tag := snippet.find('div', {'data-marker': 'item-specific-params'}), Tag):
        details = details_tag.get_text(strip=True)

        offer = normalize('NFKC', unescape(offer_tag.get_text(strip=True))) if isinstance(
            offer_tag := details_tag.find_next(
                'div', class_=offer_re), Tag
        ) else ''

    if isinstance(salary_tag := snippet.find('span', class_=salary_tag_re), Tag):
        salary = normalize('NFKC', unescape(salary_format_re.sub(
            ' ', salary_tag.get_text(strip=True)
        ).replace(b'\xe2\x80\x94'.decode('utf-8'), '-')))

    if isinstance(employer_tag := snippet.find('div', class_=employer_tag_re), Tag):
        employer_title = title_tag.get_text() if isinstance(title_tag := employer_tag.find(
            'div', class_=employer_title_re
        ), Tag) else ''

        employer_profile_link = base_url + link_tag.get('href') if isinstance(
            link_tag := employer_tag.find('a'), Tag
        ) else ''

    if isinstance(location_tag := snippet.find('div', class_=location_tag_re), Tag):
        location = location_tag.get_text(strip=True)

    return {
        'position': position,
        'details': details,
        'offer': offer,
        'salary': salary,
        'employer': employer_title,
        'employer_profile': employer_profile_link,
        'location': location,
        'link': link,
    }


data: List[Dict[str, Any]] = []
for item in soup.find_all('div', {'data-marker': 'item'}):
    data += [parse_snippet(item)]

with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as dump:
    json.dump(
        data,
        dump,
        ensure_ascii=False,
        indent=2
    )

pd.DataFrame(data).to_excel('result.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

Вывод json:

```json
[
  {
    "position": "Водитель трубоплетевоза вахта",
    "details": "Вахтовый метод · С проживанием · Выплаты дважды в месяц · Опыт более 3 лет",
    "offer": "Требуется Водитель плетевоза (Урал с полуприцепом). Вахта. \n\nВакансия открыта на АО «газстройпром» — Основным видом деятельности компании являются производство строительно-монтажных работ. Работа в Вахтовом посёлке Харасавэй (Уникальное по размерам запасов газа месторождение), там строится крупное Гкм (Газоконденсатная станция). \n\nМы предлагаем: \n\n— График работы: вахта 60/30 по 10 рабочих часов + 2 часа ночная ставка +10%;\n— Трудоустройство официальное, зарплата 2 раза в месяц четко на карту;\n— Мы предоставляем 3-х разовое питание — Сытный завтрак, обед и ужин из трех блюд;\n— Работники проживают в общежитии. Есть душ, прачечная, телевизор, шкафы и комнаты досуга и баня. \n— Спец. Одежду предоставляем бесплатно;\n— Оплачиваем перелет! \n— Почасовая оплата труда: 410.00 Ставка / час, 125 000 месяц/ и за полную вахту 60 смен — от 250 000 руб. На руки. \n\nНаши ожидания: \n\n— Базовое среднее или средне-специальное, прошедшие соответствующую подготовку, имеющие права категории В, С, Е. Наличие сертификатов, лицензий, допусков: категории транспортных средств «В», «С», «Е»;\n— Опыт работы на трубоплетевоза марки Урал или аналогичных от 3 лет;\n— Сертификат о прививке.\n\nПриведи друга и получи 5 000 руб. Вместе работать веселее! \n\nЗвоните по телефону. Мы ждем Вас!",
    "salary": "125 000 - 250 000 ₽",
    "employer": "ЕЦС",
    "employer_profile": "https://www.avito.ru/i210248769?src=from_items_list_seller_info",
    "location": "р-н Октябрьский",
    "link": "https://www.avito.ru/izhevsk/vakansii/voditel_trubopletevoza_vahta_2303330376"
  },
  {
    "position": "Администратор в косметологию Краса Лайн",
    "details": "Сменный график · Салон красоты · Опыт не имеет значения",
    "offer": "Заботливый администратор мы ищем тебя. \n\nВ косметологию Краса Лайн требуется администратор. \nОпыт работы или большое желание Работать у Нас! \n\nУсловия работы: \nГрафик работы 4 дня в наделю в 2 студиях попеременно ( Петрова 51 и Пушкинская 291а).\n\nГрафик работы С 10:00-20:00.\n\nВыход за смену 800₽ + процент от общей выручки + личные продажи косметики.\n\nТребования: \nГраммотная речь.\nУмение продавать.\nУмение принимать.\nСамостоятельные решения.\nПонимание соц сетей. \nКоммуникабельность.\n\nЧто мы прeдлагаем: \n\nдружный колектив.\nЗapабoтная плата один paз в неделю.\nВсе процессы автоматизированны, что делает работу максимально понятной. \nКарьерный рост.\n\nТы наш идеальный администратор, если: \n\nТы честен, ответственен и внимателен, \nСвято чтишь дедлайны и выполняешь задачи даже раньше них.\nТы всегда ориентирован в первую очередь на результат.\nГотов учиться и развиваться. \nНе боишься новых задач, с которыми раньше не сталкивался, делаешь их с интересом и всегда доводишь до результата. \n\nМы не подходим друг другу, если: \n-Если ты не умеешь принимать самостоятельные решения;\n-Если ты останавливаешься, не закрыв вопрос или не решив проблему. \n-Имеешь вредные привычки ( курение).\n\nЖдём Ваши Резюме или краткое описание в Вайбер.\n\nПожалуйста, укажите в заявке: \nФио.\nНомер телефона.\nОбразование, опыт работы.\nИнтересные факты о себе — коротко.\nСсылки на Инстаграм и вконтакте.\nОбязательно напишите, Почему вы хотите работать в нашем салоне.\n\nИтак, если ты тот, кто нужен, то сразу пиши нам! Помни, что уже на этом этапе есть конкуренция! \n\nДалее мы свяжемся с тобой!",
    "salary": "25 000 - 35 000 ₽",
    "employer": "Александра",
    "employer_profile": "https://www.avito.ru/user/cc8b50367ea42d838aca739a99d2e922/profile?src=search_seller_info",
    "location": "р-н Устиновский",
    "link": "https://www.avito.ru/izhevsk/vakansii/administrator_v_kosmetologiyu_krasa_layn_2332236145"
  },
...
  {
    "position": "Водитель вилочного погрузчика",
    "details": "Полный день · Склад · Выплаты дважды в месяц · Опыт более 1 года",
    "offer": "Описание работодателя: на склад упаковки требуется водитель вилочного погрузчика.\nТребования: опыт работы от года.\nОбязанности: погрузка и выгрузка транспорта.\nУсловия:5/2, 8-17.00, официальное трудоустройство, соц. Пакет.",
    "salary": "30 000 - 35 000 ₽",
    "employer": "Алексей",
    "employer_profile": "https://www.avito.ru/user/d9d1fcf3638fa03865dcbecbb5b5abb3/profile?src=search_seller_info",
    "location": "р-н Ленинский",
    "link": "https://www.avito.ru/izhevsk/vakansii/voditel_vilochnogo_pogruzchika_2257156810"
  },
  {
    "position": "Водитель такси в аренду",
    "details": "Неполный день · Опыт не имеет значения",
    "offer": "Гарантия Заработка до 6400 руб в День.\n\nРабота водителем такси на своем авто или аренда авто. Подключение для работы у партнера Яндекс Такси займет 5 минут. Сразу сможете работать. \n\nРабота на личном авто: \n\n— Средний доход чистыми (8-10ч) — 4200 ₽ / день.\n\n— Выплаты каждый день на карту 24/7 (моментальные).\n\n— Полностью свободный график (без штрафов).\n\n— Можете работать в любой точке города.\n\n— Заказов очень много.\n\n— Лучший парк с приоритетом в городе Ижевск.\n\n— Комиссия Яндекс. Такси 12% + 3% парк.\n\n— Авто в такси числиться Не будет.\n\n— Удаленное подключение за 2 минуты.\n\nЖмите Откликнуться на Авито / Пишите на whatsapp / Звоните. Оформляем круглосуточно без выходных 24/7. \n\nАвто на аренду: \n\n— Kia Rio 2015-2019 (Мкп/Акп, газ/бензин) — 1400-1600₽.\n\n— Lifan Solano 2016-2018 (Мкп, бензин) — 800₽.\n\n— Renault Logan 2015-2018 (Мкп, газ) — 1200-1400₽.\n\n— Renault Fluence 2018 (Мкп/Акп, газ/бензин) — 1500-1750₽.\n\n— Hyundai Solaris 2019 (Мкп/Акп, метан/бензин) от 1500₽.\n\n— Lada Granta/Vesta 2015-2018 (Мкп, газ) — 1100-1400₽.\n\n— Skoda Rapid 2017 (Акп/Мкп, бензин/газ) — 1350-1650₽.\n\n— Skoda Octavia 2018 (Мкп, бензин) — 1500-1900₽.\n\n— Datsun on-DO 2018-2019 (Мкп, бензин) — 950-1100₽.\n\n— Volkswagen Polo 2018 (Мкп/Акп, газ/бензин) — 1500-1800₽.\n\n— 1-ый день аренды бесплатно. Залога нет. Авто в бренде и с лицензией.\n\nАвто на зарплатный проект: \n\n— Kia Optima 2018-2019 (Мкп/Акп, бензин).\n\n— Skoda Rapid 2017 (Акп/Мкп, бензин/газ).\n\n— Skoda Octavia 2017-2018 (Мкп/бензин).\n\n— Hyundai Solaris 2019 (Акп/газ).\n\n— Volkswagen Polo 2018 (Мкп/Акп, газ/бензин).\n\n— Toyota Camry 2018-2019 (Мкп/Акп, бензин).\n\n— Datsun On Do 2019 (Акп).\n\n— Kia Rio 2016-2018 (Мкп/Акп, газ/бензин).\n\n— Имеется оклад: график 5/2 — 40000₽, график 6/1 — 60000₽.\n\n— На зарплатном проекте платить за авто не надо, мойка, смена и топливо тоже за счет парка. Доход делится 50/50 или 60/40. Имеются различные графики работы 2/2, 3/3, 6/1 7/0 и т. Д. \n\n— Тарифы: Эконом, К, К+.\n\nЖмите Откликнуться на Авито / Пишите на whatsapp / Звоните. Оформляем круглосуточно без выходных 24/7. \n\nБудет небольшим плюсом: \nОпыт работы в сторонних агрегаторах (Ситимобил, Ди Ди, Везет и др.) и если вы работали на вакансии курьер или доставщик в сервисах доставки. \n\nВакансию можно найти по запросам: \n«вакансия водитель, подключение такси, авто на газу, моментум, работать водителем такси, юбер, низкая комиссия, яндекс про, ежедневная оплата, вакансия водитель яндекс, яндекс такси, таксопарк, условия такси, тариф бизнес, тариф комфорт, без залога, водитель такси, водитель категории Б, яндекс го, работа в яндекс такси, на авто компании, устроиться водителем, яндекс такси подключение, аренда авто, яндекс работа, оформление в такси, подработка такси, аренда с выкупом, парк, зарплатный проект, убер, регистрация в такси».",
    "salary": "115 500 ₽",
    "employer": "Работа Мир",
    "employer_profile": "https://www.avito.ru/i214521677?src=from_items_list_seller_info",
    "location": "р-н Первомайский",
    "link": "https://www.avito.ru/izhevsk/vakansii/voditel_taksi_v_arendu_2315655919"
  }
]
```

> *Ну и excel (смотря как удобно)*

> *Если хотите парсить телефоны, придется к selenium присматриваться*